# Generic with object and method name

Tags: typescript, generics

This is a simplified example of passing to a generic function an object and the name of a method in that object.

```
function invoke<TYPE_OBJ extends object>(obj: TYPE_OBJ, methodName: keyof TYPE_OBJ){

    return obj[methodName](); //*** This expression is not callable. Type '{}' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
}
```

What am I missing to specify that the methodName corresponds to a callable thing?

ts version 4.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly how is you case, however this seems working fine:

```
//example type
type TYPE_OBJ = {
  foo: () => void;
};

function invoke<TYPE_OBJ extends Record<string, () => void>>(obj: TYPE_OBJ, methodName: keyof TYPE_OBJ) {

  return obj[methodName]();
}
```